# CSS animation works only after second click

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate movement of ball with css. The ball moves to the coordinates of click, and the animation should take 1s. However, for some reason, when I click for the first time, the ball changes its position immediately. After this, the animation works properly with next clicks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#field {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 10px groove black;
      background-color: green;
      cursor: pointer;

    }

#ball {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      transition-property: top, left;
      transition-duration: 1s;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="field">
<img src="https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"> 
</div>

<script>
"use strict"


function moveElement(elem, x, y){
    
    if (elem.isConnected){
        
        let rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        //console.log(elem.parentElement);
        let rect2 = elem.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(elem.parentElement.style['top'], elem.parentElement.style['left']);
        elem.style['top'] = y - rect.height/2 - parseInt(elem.parentElement.style['top']) + 'px';
        elem.style['left']= x - rect.width/2 - parseInt(elem.parentElement.style['left']) + 'px';
    }
    else{
        alert("No element");
    }
}

field.style['top']=300 + 'px';
field.style['left']=150 + 'px';
field.style['position']='absolute';
ball.style['position'] = 'absolute';
//field.addEventListener('click', (event) => {console.log(event.x, event.y);})

//ball.style['position'] = 'absolute';
console.log("BALL", ball.getBoundingClientRect().top, ball.getBoundingClientRect().left);

field.onclick = (event) => {//console.log("BALL_START",ball.getBoundingClientRect().left,ball.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    moveElement(ball, event.pageX, event.pageY);}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to set the initial position of the ball in CSS, like this:

```
#ball {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: top, left;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    // add initial position, top left corner
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```